# Can we change the <soap:address location> dynamically - with JAX-WS

Tags: spring, jax-ws, jaxws-maven-plugin

I am new to soap web services,wanted to know can we change the location of soap:address according to the environment it is deployed. I am using jaxws-spring

```
<binding name="HelloWorldWSPortBinding" type="tns:HelloWorldWS">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
<operation name="getHelloWorld"></binding>
<service name="HelloWorldWSService">
<port name="HelloWorldWSPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldWSPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8095/WebServicesExample/hello" />
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: what you want to change the soap address location to ? Can you give an example of what you are expecting in the location field ? It looks like your tomcat is running on port 8095 and you are accessing it through localhost

Comment: @sariq, when i run locally it is taking the address correctly, but when i deploy it on the production server it should take the production url right? but for me it is coming as loclhost:8080/WebservicesExample/Hello. how can i share this wsdl to the client

Comment: What error do you get when you deploy on production server and which URL you are trying to access ? The production server URL if you can mention.

Comment: no error, only thing is it will point to localhost . I cannot share the production url here